# MainWindow do not process events and user actions concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a PyQt5 MainWindow that I made using Qt Designer.

This window is supposed to crawl a site and list crawled links in a TreeView once they're found.

I am able to do that by creating a  model, `QStandardItemModel` each time a new link is crawled, adding all links to the model and then set the model to the tree with `TreeView.setModel(model)`, and then I'd call `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()`so the window is updated. While the software crawles the site, the window does not respond to user interactions, until `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()` is executed.

How can I update my TreeView with the latest crawled link and still have my window intractable during the crawling process?

Here's my code

```
def start(self):
    ## start crawling
    self.populate_tree(crawled_links)

def populate_tree(self, links):
    data = []
    for index in links:
        item = (links[index]['from'], [])
        for link in links[index]['url']:
            item[1].append((link, []))
        data.append(item)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.__add_items(model, data)
    self.treeView.setModel(model)
    self.treeView.expandAll()
    self.treeView.scrollToBottom()
    self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()

def __add_items(self, model, data):
    for text, children in data:
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
        model.appendRow(item)
        if children:
            self.__add_items(item, children)
```

if it's any help, `crawled_links` list looks like this:

```
crawled_links = {
0:{
    'url': {
        'one.html',
        'three.html'
        },
    'from':
        'site1.com'
    },
1:{
    'url': {
        'two.html'
        },
    'from':
        'site1.com'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `processEvents()` is a bad practice, they should only be used for certain special tasks and as you see does not solve the problem.

The solution is to perform the task on a thread and send it through signals to the thread of the GUI.

---

```
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Helper(QtCore.QObject):
     resultChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

     def start_crawling(self):
         crawled_links = {}
         # processing
         self.resultChanged.emit(crawled_links)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
     def __init__(self, parent=None)
         QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.helper = Helper()
         self.helper.resultChanged.connect(self.populate_tree)

     def start(self):
         # start crawling
         threading.Thread(target=self.helper.start_crawling, daemon=True).start()


     def populate_tree(self, crawled_links)
         ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't think about threading at all. It's my first time programming something like this

Comment: Although, this did fix my problem, I'm now faced with another. I want to pause the thread when it  reaches login page so a login dialog can be opened to get user credentials, and then resume thread when login is successful. How can I do that?